# Divergenceless proving

Tags: partial-differential-equations, problem-solving, tensor-products

We can define a topological current,
\begin{equation}
J_{top}^u = \frac{1}{2v} \epsilon^{\mu \nu} \partial_\nu \phi
\end{equation}
How to prove it divergenceless? where the the condition is $$\partial_uJ=0.$$

Comment: What is $\epsilon$? and your free indices does not match on left and right side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In answering this question, I am going to make a few assumptions which clarify the OP's statements and (hopefully) refine some of the definitions, both implicit and explicit, inherent in his post.  I am going to go ahead and do this without resorting to the process of commenting and waiting for responses before answering; with luck, I'll hit the mark.

First of all, I'm taking the first equation, which defines $J$ (and please note I'm dropping the subscript "$top$" here), to read

$J^\mu = \frac{1}{2v}\epsilon^{\mu \nu} \partial_\nu \phi$,

and the second to be

$\partial_\mu J^\mu = 0$.

These assumptions merely correct what appear to be typographical errors, and make the indexing scheme consistent.  Finally, I take $\epsilon^{\mu \nu}$ to be an antisymmetric symbol on two indices, meaning

1.)  $\epsilon^{\mu \nu} = 0$ for $\mu = \nu$,

2.)  $\epsilon^{\mu \nu} = (-1)^{\mu + \nu + 1}$ for $\nu > \mu$,

3.)  $\epsilon^{\mu \nu} = -\epsilon^{\nu \mu}$ for $\nu < \mu$;

where it is assumed the indices run from $1$ to $N$, where $N$ is the dimension of the space under consideration.  With these conventions, and assuming $v$ is constant and $\phi$ is sufficiently smooth, so that $\partial_\mu \partial_\nu \phi =  \partial_\nu \partial_\mu \phi$, we have

$\partial_\alpha J^\mu = \frac{1}{2v}\epsilon^{\mu \nu} \partial_\alpha \partial_\nu \phi$;

then contracting on the indices $\alpha$, $\mu$, i.e., taking $\alpha = \mu$ and summing yields

$\partial_\mu J^\mu = \frac{1}{2v}\epsilon^{\mu \nu} \partial_\mu \partial_\nu \phi = -\frac{1}{2v}\epsilon^{\nu \mu} \partial_\mu \partial_\nu \phi = -\frac{1}{2v}\epsilon^{\nu \mu} \partial_\nu \partial_\mu \phi = -\partial_\nu J^\nu = -\partial_\mu J^\mu$,

whence

$\partial_\mu J^\mu = 0$,

since we are not operating over a field of characteristic 2!

Hope this helps.  Cheers.

Comment: In the last line you wrote, $\partial_\mu J^\mu = 0$. Is it from the trace operations?

Comment: @Complex Guy:  The preceeding equation asserts that $\partial_\mu J^\mu = -\partial_\mu J^\mu$, i.e., $\partial_\mu J^\mu$ is equal to its own negative.  The conclusion follows from this, as well as does my little jest about characteristic 2! ;)

Comment: So the assumption isn't true I gave?

Comment: I think we need to prove the 2nd condition to be divergenceless the 1st equation. Isn't it?

Comment: @Complex Guy:  to what assumption do you refer?  My read of your question, which I believe I explained in my answer, is that the first equation *defines* $J^\mu$, so if we grant a $J^\mu$ of this form, the second equation follows.

Comment: Ohh Got it now  thanks.

Comment: @Complex Guy: no promlem-o, my pleasure!